# Show content of specific line number from a file

Tags: awk, sed, posix

So say i have a file with content on each lines, know the number of lines in advance and want to know the content of specific lines, i can do:

```bsh
awk 'NR==10' file
```

But while i already know one way (using `awk`), I'm curious about other methods (`perl`, `awk` etc).

How can i know the content of specific lines?

Comment: To have any chance of being on-topic and answerable you'd have to put some kind of boundaries on that question otherwise you can get answers in C, Java, Assembly, shell read loops. etc., etc. For example you could say ".... using mandatory POSIX tools" (but then that would exclude perl). There's several ways to do this just with awk alone so it's not at all clear what the actual purpose of this question is.

Comment: The purpose of this question was "to get an alternative" to the proposed/already known solution...And yeah, i did thought of using the term "POSIX" but then, as you mentioned too, that would have excluded other valid answer like `perl`...I don't think i mind if it also have answer in `C`, but honestly not sure how to phrase it so it's clear that i don't mind if it's done in any other langs...Thanks for the insight btw :) @EdMorton

Comment: My point is that with such a wide scope there are literally hundreds if not thousands of alternatives (multiply X tools/languages by Y alternatives within each language - I could list at least a dozen alternatives off the top of my head just using awk) so as written it's not a good question for this forum. Plus you already accepted the first answer you got (which only lists 8 alternatives) so it's hard to understand what the point of the question was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '10p' file

sed '10!d' file

perl -ne 'print if $. == 10' file

head -n 10 file | tail -n 1

tail -n +10 file | head -n 1

printf '10p\n' | ed -s file

printf '10p\n' | ex file

printf '10p\n' | vi -e file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Another awk method  ===> To display 10th line

en@praveen:/tmp$ awk 'NR >9 && NR < 11'  filename
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('filename','r')
print m.readlines()[9].strip
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but your AWK variant would be better as `awk 'NR == 10' filename`.